# IScroll is not defined - FoundationPress & Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, zurb-foundation, fullpage.js

I'have an error when using fullpage.js module with FoundationPress.

My import :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'slick-carousel';
import 'fullpage.js/vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js';
import 'fullpage.js';
```

I need scrolloverflow.min.js for this : create a scroll for the section/slide in case its content is bigger than the height of it

But I still have an issus when compiling project:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: IScroll is not defined
```

My js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    navigation: true,
    scrollOverflow: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    anchors: ['home', 'page1', 'page2'],
    menu: '#myMenu'
  });
});
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Look at the possible solutions [in this topic](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2250).